# Como obter ID de Chave Primaria das informações de uma linha clicada no ListView?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

Olá, eu sou novo em programação Android e estou fazendo um projeto do qual eu preciso fazer um CRUD com um litView, de qualquer forma, eu já tenho ele exibindo os dados, porém gostaria de saber como eu faço para obter o ID de chave primaria de um registro por exemplo, que está sendo exibido em uma linha do listView da qual eu cliquei. E não a posição do elemento no listVIew.

Ja tentei procurar diversos exemplos na internet e também tentei no Stack inglês, pois todos apresentam métodos que pegam o valor de posição do elemento no listView e não o valor de Id da informação do Banco, o que não resolve o meu problema.

Pois para deixar mais claro, vou exemplificar uma situação:
Tem dois fatores, um é a linha do listview (por exemplo, posição 1);
E outro é a linha do registro do banco(por exemplo, ID de valor 5) que está sendo exibido na posição 1 do listView.

Pois eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para obter o valor 5 (do ID do Banco) ao clicar na posição 1 do listVIew.

Uma das minha tentativas:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                textView.setText("The item you clicked is : " + selectedItem);
             }
          });



listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            
                textView.setText("The item you clicked is : " + id);
//Or
                textView.setText("The item you clicked is: "+position);

             }
          });
```

Todos eles aparentemente pegam o valor de posição da linha do list, e não do ID do registro do SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, beleza? Não sei se você está usando um custom adapter, porém eu faria meu listView com um custom adapter ([aqui tem um exemplo de como fazer](https://www.alura.com.br/artigos/personalizando-uma-listview-no-android)).

A lista a ser exibida seria uma lista do tipo Item (List) (Item é uma classe para representar os itens, dei o nome de Item mas pode ser o nome que você desejar) e, nessa classe, teria um atributo para representar o ID no banco de dados.

```
public class Item{
    private int id;
    private String conteudo;

    public Item(int id, String conteudo){
        this.id = id;
        this.conteudo = conteudo;

    }

}
```

Na hora que você preencher a lista, você adiciona o ID do banco de dados para cada item.
No custom adapter eu faria uma função para me retornar o item na posição informada estilo essa:

```
public Item getItemAtPosition(int position){
    return list.get(position)
}
```

E, o click no item, ficaria algo assim:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Item item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
                 textView.setText("The item you clicked is : " + item.id);
             }
          });
```

Com isso você conseguiria pegar o id do banco de dados do item que foi clicado